# Django application assistance?

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Hi everyone I am new to django and could use help building an ERP system with it. Can anyone assist me, i have discord if you are interested in helping. I figured we could communicate better on it. Please help me with django I am going nuts

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Unfortunately I cannot comment because of low reputation points)

One of the first and most important steps of building a web application / service (that uses models) is to identify the needs and features and then implement them on models. You can start by working on your application's models and then the rest of development process will be easier to work on.